# Cantor Intersection Theorem Without Closedness, counterexample

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers

The Cantor Intersection Theorem is that

> Let $\{S_1,S_2,S_3,...\}$ be a countable collection of nonempty sets in $\mathbb R$ such that:
>
> 1. $S_{k+1} \subset S_k$ for $k=1,2,3...$
> 2. Each $S_k$ is closed and $S_1$ is bounded,
>
> then the intersection $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty S_k$ is closed and nonempty.

My question is that, what if for some $S_k$ is not closed, how does it fail?

What is the counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most trivial one would be

$$S_k= (0,\frac{1}{k}).$$

Note that $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty S_k$ is empty.

If only finitely many of them are not closed, then the result still hold.

Comment: I think you meant to say "If only finitely many are not closed$\dots$"

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Thanks, edited.